# Login Via Jmeter for ASP page does not work

Tags: jmeter, performance, c#, stress-testing, .net

Currently I have a page that has been created in .net when I used the HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder and try to record login page, the page is sending a post request but the page is redirect to same. All the parameters are captured but upon submission of the page it redirects back to the same page.

So while playing the recorded stuffs it does not allow to proceed. The page does not have any API written in back end.

I have even tried to correlate __RequestVerificationToken and ufprt parameters instead of viewstate/eventvalidation but that didn't work as well.

Can you please refer to these images and help me with it? 
Or is there an alternative solution to it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

JMeter's built-in script recorder tends to create problems with the test scripts when the URL is SSL encrypted (HTTPS). This may be because JMeter uses proxy when recording the scripts and while running the recorded test script the proxy isn't available.

For recording the Performance Test scripts for JMeter I prefer to use Blazemeter's Chrome Extension.

The extension records all the required credentials, cookies and sessions for the page access and also works well with HTTPS.

All you require for this is,

to be logged in with a Blazemeter account (which is free).

Record your test script as you browser in Google Chrome.

Once you are done with it export the recorded script in JMX format.

Load the JMX in JMeter and make any changes required.

Add some Listeners and you are good to go!

Comment: Used the extension as well but the problem still exists. It redirects to the same page.

Comment: Can you share your script along with some screenshots of your configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the provided images I'm not very surprised to see your login attempt failing.

1. Your first screenshot shows that you're using login POST method as a very first request
2. Your third screenshot shows an internal server error

You need to issue a GET request to login page prior to the POST one as "normal" user would do, like:

- GET request to the Login Page

  - Extract `__RequestVerificationToken` and `ufprt` with i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- POST to the Login Page - pass credentials and variables holding dynamic values of the `__RequestVerificationToken` and `ufprt` parameters.

---

If for some reason you are not able to do it on your own - there is an alternative solution for JMeter test scripts recording which is smart enough to detect and correlate dynamic parameters automatically. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for details.

Comment: I tried Using Regular Expression Extractor with those two parameters but the problem still exists.